# convention in generating request ID for RestrictionsManager.requestPermission()

Tags: android

The method [RestrictionsManager.requestPermission](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager.html#requestPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.PersistableBundle%29) requires a request ID as one of its parameters. Per Android doc, it's an unique ID to identify the request. Currently I just use `123` which works fine for me. Are there any conventions/rules about this request ID generation that I should follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The request id is simply for you to help identify which permission request you get an answer for.

If you for example would happen to send several permission requests you can identify them when you receive the request result in:

```
onRequestPermissionsResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
```

The `requestCode` is however limited to a maximum value of `255` (lower 8 bits of int).